# Loop through SQL results and do a IF, ELSE

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a select, like:

```
SELECT item, group, paid FROM table WHERE group=120
```

The result will be:

```
item    group    paid
A       120      1
B       120      1
C       120      1
D       120      0
```

I need to loop through the result and check if all the itens have paid = 1 do something, instead, do another thing. Thanks.

This is what I have:

```
<%      
    SET Lista= MSSQL.Execute("SELECT item, group, paid FROM table WHERE group=120")
        Do While Not Lista.EOF
        paid= Lista("paid")
            IF paid= 1 THEN
                Response.Write "1"
            ELSE
                Response.Write "0"      
            END IF
        Loop
%>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is very common and can be easily be found with a quick search.

Comment: Why vote down? I don't know how to check for ALL the values...

Comment: It was voted down because you are asking for code, instead of asking how to fix your own code, or asking about the principals of how to do it. Just asking for code is not good. There are sites to rent coders for that.

Comment: Ok sorry, i will always publish my actual code... i just done that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The loop is probably not working because you're missing a `Lista.MoveNext` before `Loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET Lista= MSSQL.Execute("SELECT item, group, paid FROM table WHERE group=120")
Lista.Filter = "paid = 0"
If (Lista.Eof) Then
Response.write("0")
Else
Response.Write("1")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this slight modification...

```
 <%      
        SET Lista= MSSQL.Execute("SELECT item, group, paid FROM table WHERE group=120")
            While Not Lista.EOF
            paid = Lista("paid")
                IF paid= 1 THEN
                    Response.Write "1"
                ELSE
                    Response.Write "0"      
                END IF
           Lista.MoveNext
           Wend
    %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will list the itens. I am trying to do is: If ALL the records=1 do something, if there is one or more= 0 do another thing. thanks